# Halt http requests untill cache is ready without polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I have a use case where my http requests are caching the intermediate result on server.
If the cache is not present the request builds it by requesting another server.

These requests are fired in succession (loop) using AJAX to Node Server and the number of requests can be in range of 50 to 500.

**The Problem:**
Since the requests are made in a loop and the cache is already not present first few of them all try to build the cache and sometimes consequent requests find the semi-built cache, which returns wrong result.

I can circumvent this problem with polling:

```
(function next(){
    if(!wait){
       fs.readFile(cacheFile, function(err){
           if(err) {
               wait = true;
               createCache(); // sets wait = false;
           } else {
               useCache();
           }
       });
    } else {
        setTimeout(next,waitTime);
    }
})();
```

**My Query:**
Can the requests be halted without polling, and continue only after the first request has completed the cache building process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in combination with Futures/Promise. You can take this [one](https://npmjs.org/package/future).
Outside of the scope define var cachePromise and you can use something like this below:

```
if (!cachePromise) {
  cachePromise = require('future').create()
  buildCache(function() {
    cachePromise.fulfill();
  });
}

cachePromise.when(next); // this one triggers next route in middleware stack
```

Put the code in route stack before the route which gives result and you are good to go.

thanks.